# python choice in some of ROS packages

Tags: ros, python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder why some .py files start with

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

like in /camera_calibration/cameracalibrator.py
while the others are with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

like in /rosbag/bag2png.py

The choice could be critical if one have two copies of python, which is the case in Mac OSX. I have a default preinstalled python version (/usr/bin/python) and the other one is installed through homebrew (is in my PATH).

And a side question have somebody installed ros with a default python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107936/python-choice-in-some-of-ros-packages/) by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 709 on 2013-12-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there's a specific reason why some scripts use `/usr/bin/python`. For 99% of the users (on Ubuntu, for example) it doesn't make a difference, since they use the default python, so the script works for them either way. But you're right, the `env` version is more flexible, so my suggestion is whenever you run into a bug caused by this, write a bug report in the package's bug tracker.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-16**:
I would add that if the script depends on python2.7, rather have `#!/usr/bin/env python2`. See answer by spease.